# Collect form values to make literal array for loop to display values using getElementById() and the innerHTML property?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms, getelementbyid

I am totally new to javascript and trying to understand how to collect multiple values from a form to collect to make an array, which then will have another function to loop through a for loop array to display in an unordered list by innerHTML-ing the element into the dom. However, it's saying that ul.appendChild is not a function? I'm not do not know what means and have searched. Here is my code to give you a better idea. I don't want just the answer, if someone could point out what's possibly wrong and steer me the right direction? Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/rtomino/eu10htcm/2/

```
<form name="contact" id="contactForm" action="#">
    <div class="six columns">
      <label for="firstName" class="req">First Name:</label>
      <input class="u-full-width" type="text" name="userInput[]" required>
    </div>
    <div class="six columns">
      <label for="lastName" class="req">Last Name:</label>
      <input class="u-full-width" type="text" name="userInput[]" required>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="six columns">
    <label for="email" class="req">Email:</label>
    <input class="u-full-width" type="email" placeholder="test@test.com" name="userInput[]" pattern="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?" required>
  </div>
  <div class="six columns">
    <label for="tel">Phone:</label>
    <input class="u-full-width" type="tel" placeholder="(000)-000-0000" name="userInput[]">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="six columns">
    <div class="required"><em>* Required</em></div>
  </div>
  <div class="six columns">
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit">
    <p class="clear">Clear fields</p>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

```
window.onload = init;

function init() {
  var button = document.getElementById("submit");
  button.onclick = handleButtonClick;

}

function handleButtonClick(e) {

  var collectInput = document.getElementsByName("userInput[]");

  if (collectInput == "") {
    alert("Please fill the form");
  } else {

    for (var i = 0; i < collectInput.length; i++) {
      var myArray = collectInput[i].value;

      var li = document.createElement("li");

      li.innerHTML = myArray;

      var ul = document.getElementById("userInformation").innerHTML += myArray;

      ul.appendChild(li);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and welcome to JavaScript ;)

Well lets take a look on your javascript code

```
var myArray = collectInput[i].value;

var li = document.createElement("li");

li.innerHTML = myArray;

var ul = document.getElementById("userInformation").innerHTML += myArray;

ul.appendChild(li);
```

So first you take collectInput[i] and save it to myArray variable.

```
var myArray = collectInput[i].value;
```

Then you create li element and sets myArray as its innerHtml

```
var li = document.createElement("li");

li.innerHTML = myArray;
```

And that is perfectly fine. But then you do this

```
var ul = document.getElementById("userInformation").innerHTML += myArray;
```

You want to find "userInformation" element and save it to local ul variable but instead you take its innerHTML and adds myArray to it. So instead of storing "userInformation" DOM element in your ul variable you store .innerHTML + myArray string there.

So to make it work change this line to

```
var ul = document.getElementById("userInformation")
```

And then it should work just fine.

Good luck with Javascript ;)

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked and I fully understand step by step. I really appreciate it.